# resetPassword problem for enterprise users when called from a community?

Tags: customer-community, reset-password

I'm working within a custom application in a customer community that is used by both community-license users and Salesforce enterprise users.  There is a custom Visualforce page where an application admin can select a user and reset the password.  The VF Controller is using the standard System.resetPassword() method.

We are finding that when an enterprise user receives this password reset email, the user can't get to the expected password reset page.  Instead, it eventually redirects to the community login screen.

The password reset URL for these enterprise users is based on the community's URL, and it seems that these users cannot change password through the community -- it has to be through the enterprise URL, like what you get when you reset password via Setup.

Has anyone run into this and found a workaround?

(Of course community users have no trouble with password resets through this Visualforce page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce support told me to use Site.forgotPassword() instead.  He demonstrated how it works for both community users and enterprise users.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into [this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298845/forgot-password-interstitial-page) as well and got around it by using a VisualForce Email Template with Substitute:

```
 <a href="{!SUBSTITUTE($Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails,"_nc_external/identity/ui/login/ForgotPasswordInterstitial","secur/forgotpassword.jsp")}">{!$Network.Name}</a>
                   </apex:outputPanel>
```

I can't seem to post this to the other thread, so hopefully people can find and be helped by this!  Also, if you're running into issues with the change password VisualForce page including merge fields, you can see [the solution here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45896/salesforce-visualforce-email-template-recipient-name-does-not-have-the-correc/387834#387834).