# Forgot Password Interstitial Page

Tags: community, rest-api, forgot-your-password, reset-password

I am facing the following problem, which may be a result of my misunderstanding of the whole concept. Let my try to explain. We use one community. The community users have in their profile the flag **Don't immediately expire links in forgot password emails** checked. According to documentation I would expect that the user resetting their passwords would first get the ForgotPasswordInterstitial page and after confirmation there that they will be redirected to the page to set their password. When user uses forgot password link the Interstitial Page displays correctly.  To reset the password the forgot password controller uses method Site.forgotPassword with the username as an argument.

There is also a possibility to reset the password using an API and in this case the Interstitial Page does not show up. Unlike forgot password controller, the API uses System.resetPassword with user's Id and a value true as arguments.

My assumption is that Site method is available only if you connect to a Site, which you don't using the API - API uses integration user. Because of that I cannot use Site method in the API. Please correct me if I am wrong.

My second assumption is that the Interstitial Page shows up only when Site method is used, but not when System method is used. Also correct me if I am wrong.
I would appreciate any of your thoughts on this problem. I tried to search through the Salesforce documentation but they are quite scarce.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I actually don't know how to separate the questions. I mean it is one problem which could be summarized like "Why I don't get Interstitial Page when resetting the password through the API?". The rest is just explanation how two different reset options have been set up and what I did in my course of investigation.