# How to Bypass ForgotPasswordInterstitial Visualforce Page during Experience Forgot Password Flow

Tags: user-management, experience-cloud, reset-password

I'm working with a customer that is using an experience with 9+ languages.  We've encountered a surprising number of gaps in the language capabilities of Experience - specifically pertaining to self registration, email verification etc.  Many pages are black box and do not permit translations via the Experience nor Labels.

The experience users have in their profile the flag **Don't immediately expire links in forgot password emails** checked and this unfortunately layers in the ForgotPasswordInterstitial page.  Unfortunately, there appears to be no way to get this page to reliably translate into the user's language.  How do we translate or bypass this page (as it seems completely unnecessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this issue by using a VisualForce Email Template with `Substitute` to take the users to the expected page and not the `ForgotPasswordInterstitial` one e.g.:

```
<apex:outputPanel>
 <a href="{!SUBSTITUTE($Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails,
                 "_nc_external/identity/ui/login/ForgotPasswordInterstitial",
                 "secur/forgotpassword.jsp")}">
  {!$Network.Name}
 </a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Also, if you're running into issues with the change password VisualForce page including merge fields from the recipient record, you can [see the solution here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45896/salesforce-visualforce-email-template-recipient-name-does-not-have-the-correc/387834#387834).

Answer (score 0):

We got another solution for that without the necessity to skip a page.
It seems the page is translated, but email always redirect to english.

As the solution just add 'locale' parameter.

For example:
https://yourenvironment.sandbox.my.site.com/communityname/_nc_external/
identity/ui/login/ForgotPasswordInterstitial?
r=123456789&display=page&fpot=123456789&locale=es